# Correct way to use GeoPy Nominatim

Tags: python

I'm new on programing, and I'm using a programing tutorial which said that to use `geopy` like this:

```py
import pandas, os, geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

GeoLocator = Nominatim()
```

but after the last line I'm getting this error:

> */usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopy/geocoders/osm.py:143: UserWarning: Using Nominatim with the default "geopy/1.17.0" `user_agent` is strongly discouraged, as it violates Nominatim's ToS https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/ and may possibly cause 403 and 429 HTTP errors. Please specify a custom `user_agent` with `Nominatim(user_agent="my-application")` or by overriding the default `user_agent`: `geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "my-application"`. In geopy 2.0 this will become an exception.
>     UserWarning*

My question is, how should I change my code to fix this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should specify a user_agent. The Nominatum service runs on donated servers which have limited capacity, so specifying a user-agent field allows Open Street Map to track more easily who is using their service. See here for a more detailed [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/293615/129255).

If you don't they may block your IP address from accessing the service as that would be a violation of their terms of service.

Answer (score 10):

`nom = Nominatim(user_agent="http")`
you have to mention your useragent(HTTP) its just about IP adress